# Cant run javascript code

Tags: javascript, blockchain

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/sha256.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    class Block{
        calculateHash(){
            var cipher = CryptoJS.SHA256(this.email + this.username + this.password + this.fullname + this.telnum + this.icnum + this.previousHash);
            return cipher;
        }

        constructor(email, username, password, fullname, telnum, icnum, previousHash){
            this.email = email;
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
            this.fullname = fullname;
            this.telnum = telnum;
            this.icnum = icnum;
            this.previousHash = previousHash;
            this.hash = calculateHash();
        }



    }

    class Blockchain{
        constructor(){
            this.chain = [this.createGenesisBlock()];
        }

        createGenesisBlock(){
            return new Block("example@gmail.com", "genesisblock", "example1234", "examplename", "0123456789", "860914-01-6767", "0");
        }

        getLatestBlock(){
            return this.chain[this.chain.length - 1];
        }

        addBlock(newBlock){
            newBlock.previousHash = this.getLatestBlock().hash;
            newBlock.hash = newBlock.calculateHash;
            this.chain.push(newBlock);
        }
    }



    let Mcoin = new Blockchain();
    Mcoin.addBlock(new Block("example@gmail.com", "genesisblock", "example1234", "examplename", "0123456789", "860914-01-6767"));

    console.log(JSON.stringify(Mcoin, null, 4));
</script>
```

I've written a simple javascript blockchain code i found on youtube i don't understand why i can't run it. I did this code on a php file as i need to reference a link to use the sha256 function for my hash. At the last line, i can view my chain on console but when i go to my console it only shows this..

> Uncaught ReferenceError: calculateHash is not defined at new Block (test_code.php:18) at Blockchain.createGenesisBlock (test_code.php:31) at new Blockchain (test_code.php:27) at test_code.php:47

The dude on youtube managed to view his chain on his console but i did the exact same thing and nothing appeared. Am i doing the calculateHash() function wrongly?

Comment: Well, `calculateHash` isn’t a function that exists in that scope; it’s an instance method which works as `new Block().calculateHash` or `this.calculateHash`. If you’re referring to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVqczFZr124), the code reads `this.calculateHash`, not `calculateHash`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `this.hash = calculateHash();` to `this.hash = this.calculateHash();`

As Xufox said in the comments: `calculateHash` isn’t a function that exists in that scope; it’s an instance method which works as `new Block().calculateHash` or `this.calculateHash`.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/sha256.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    class Block{
        calculateHash(){
            var cipher = CryptoJS.SHA256(this.email + this.username + this.password + this.fullname + this.telnum + this.icnum + this.previousHash);
            return cipher;
        }

        constructor(email, username, password, fullname, telnum, icnum, previousHash){
            this.email = email;
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
            this.fullname = fullname;
            this.telnum = telnum;
            this.icnum = icnum;
            this.previousHash = previousHash;
            this.hash = this.calculateHash();
        }



    }

    class Blockchain{
        constructor(){
            this.chain = [this.createGenesisBlock()];
        }

        createGenesisBlock(){
            return new Block("example@gmail.com", "genesisblock", "example1234", "examplename", "0123456789", "860914-01-6767", "0");
        }

        getLatestBlock(){
            return this.chain[this.chain.length - 1];
        }

        addBlock(newBlock){
            newBlock.previousHash = this.getLatestBlock().hash;
            newBlock.hash = newBlock.calculateHash;
            this.chain.push(newBlock);
        }
    }



    let Mcoin = new Blockchain();
    Mcoin.addBlock(new Block("example@gmail.com", "genesisblock", "example1234", "examplename", "0123456789", "860914-01-6767"));

    console.log(JSON.stringify(Mcoin, null, 4));
</script>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8aktL5zp/1/